# newbie can't define a method in ruby for cucumber test pass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, tdd, cucumber

I am trying to learn cucumber, here's an example code from a book:

```
class Output
  def messages
    @messages ||= []
  end

  def puts(message)
    messages << message
  end
end

def output
  @output ||= Output.new
end

Given /^I am not yet playing$/ do
end

When /^I start a new game$/ do
  game = Codebreaker::Game.new(output)
  game.start
end

Then /^I should see "([^"]*)"$/ do |message|
  output.messages.should include(message)
end
```

When I run this spec, I get this error:

```
  Scenario: start game                          # features/codebreaker_starts_game.feature:7
    Given I am not yet playing                  # features/step_definitions/codebreaker_steps.rb:15
    When I start a new game                     # features/step_definitions/codebreaker_steps.rb:18
    Then I should see "Welcome to Codebreaker!" # features/step_definitions/codebreaker_steps.rb:23
      undefined method `messages' for #<RSpec::Matchers::BuiltIn::Output:0xa86a7a4> (NoMethodError)
      ./features/step_definitions/codebreaker_steps.rb:24:in `/^I should see "([^"]*)"$/'
      features/codebreaker_starts_game.feature:10:in `Then I should see "Welcome to Codebreaker!"'
    And I should see "Enter guess:"             # features/step_definitions/codebreaker_steps.rb:23
```

See that it gives `undefined method 'messages'` error, yet it is defined in the `Output` class.

If I replace `output.messages.should` with `Output.new.messages.should`, it works fine. What is the problem here?

**Edit**: Probably `output` is a keyword, in new version of rails, when I changed it to `outputz` it worked fine. An explanation of this will be accepted as an answer.

Comment: `output` is not a keyword, it is simply a method built-in to cucumber (`RSpec::Matchers::BuiltIn::Output`)...

Comment: @UriAgassi thanks, is it new, because the book uses it as a method,   can you reference the introduce of this keyword so I can accept as an answer?

Comment: Have you tried actually referencing the instance variable `@output` e.g. `@output.messages.should include(message)` right now you are calling the method `output` rather than the instance variable. Also as a side note expectations are the preferred syntax in RSpec now. Since you are just learning I would suggestion learning this way. e.g. `expect(@output.messages).to include(message)`

Comment: thanks @engineersmnky, can you recommend some up to date resources/books, I appreciate.

Comment: @user3995789 not sure about books but [This article](http://myronmars.to/n/dev-blog/2012/06/rspecs-new-expectation-syntax) should give you an idea and [BetterSpecs](http://betterspecs.org/) is also pretty good and more in depth on how to write your specs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently, the [`output` matcher](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/docs/built-in-matchers/output-matcher) has been added to rspec in version 3.0:

> The output matcher provides a way to assert that the has emitted
>   content to either `$stdout` or `$stderr`.
>
> With no arg, passes if the block outputs to_stdout or to_stderr. With
>   a string, passes if the blocks outputs that specific string to_stdout
>   or to_stderr. With a regexp or matcher, passes if the blocks outputs a
>   string to_stdout or to_stderr that matches.

Examples:

> ```
> RSpec.describe "output.to_stdout matcher" do
>   specify { expect { print('foo') }.to output.to_stdout }
>   specify { expect { print('foo') }.to output('foo').to_stdout }
>   specify { expect { print('foo') }.to output(/foo/).to_stdout }
>   specify { expect { }.to_not output.to_stdout }
>   specify { expect { print('foo') }.to_not output('bar').to_stdout }
>   specify { expect { print('foo') }.to_not output(/bar/).to_stdout }
> ```