# Rspec Cucumber: NoMethodError

Tags: ruby, rspec, cucumber

I'm followiing ['The Rspec Book'](https://pragprog.com/book/achbd/the-rspec-book) and I can't comprehend why I'm getting the following error when running cucumber.

```
Feature: code-breaker starts game

  As a code-breaker
  I want to start a game
  So that I can break the code

  Scenario: start game                          # /Users/PC/ruby/practice/rspec/codebreaker/features/codebreaker_starts_game.feature:7
    Given I am not yet playing                  # ruby/practice/rspec/codebreaker/features/step_definitions/codebreaker_steps.rb:17
    When I start a new game                     # ruby/practice/rspec/codebreaker/features/step_definitions/codebreaker_steps.rb:20
    Then I should see "Welcome to Codebreaker!" # ruby/practice/rspec/codebreaker/features/step_definitions/codebreaker_steps.rb:25
      undefined method `messages' for #<RSpec::Matchers::BuiltIn::Output:0x007fd6611fcb30> (NoMethodError)
      ./ruby/practice/rspec/codebreaker/features/step_definitions/codebreaker_steps.rb:26:in `/^I should see "(.*?)"$/'
      ./ruby/practice/rspec/codebreaker/features/codebreaker_starts_game.feature:10:in `Then I should see "Welcome to Codebreaker!"'
    And I should see "Enter guess:"             # ruby/practice/rspec/codebreaker/features/step_definitions/codebreaker_steps.rb:25

Failing Scenarios:
cucumber /Users/PC/ruby/practice/rspec/codebreaker/features/codebreaker_starts_game.feature:7 # Scenario: start game

1 scenario (1 failed)
4 steps (1 failed, 1 skipped, 2 passed)
0m0.050s

shell returned 1
```

step definitions file:

http://pastebin.com/BZZKL0wa

Note: I tried printing output.messages and it worked fine.

Comment: This may be a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26850871/newbie-cant-define-a-method-in-ruby-for-cucumber-test-pass

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that you're running into the built in `output` matcher that's part of RSpec (see https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/docs/built-in-matchers/output-matcher). Did you try printing `output.messages` within your step definition at the same point you're trying to check the output? You should get the same failure.

In any event, if you use a different method name, you should be ok.

Answer (score 2):

Peter Alfvin is right: rename the output method.  Here's what worked for me:

```
class OutputDouble
  def messages
    @messages ||= []
  end
  def puts(message)
    messages << message
  end
end

def output_double
  @output ||= OutputDouble.new
end

Given /^I am not yet playing$/ do
end

When /^I start a new game$/ do
  game = Codebreaker::Game.new(output_double)
  game.start
end

Then /^I should see "([^"]*)"$/ do |message|
  output_double.messages.should include(message)
end
```

Note that the creation method (output) has been renamed to output_double.